# jQuery collapse hide another elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working in a simple collapse system and its working fine ... but there is a extra element like summery p tag in each collapse item and when i click any item that p tag hide and full content will show ... its actually working but effect others items too .. but it should not be ...

**html code is:**

```
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <p class="summery">this is summery</p>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Full content Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapsetwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #2
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <p class="summery">this is summery2</p>  
        <div id="collapsetwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Full content Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JS code:**

```
$('.panel-heading > .panel-title').click(function(){
    $('.panel > p.summery').toggle();

});
```

**JSFIDDLE Link:** https://jsfiddle.net/arow2oxa/1/

Comment: I am not understanding your question. The content is only hidden when you click the header

Comment: Do you want that p tag to show or also be hidden?

Comment: sorry for the confusion but the solution was given below ... if you are not clear please see that solution demo ... hopefully you will understand @AmmarCSE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
$(this).closest('.panel').find('> p.summery').toggle();
```

Instead:

```
$('.panel > p.summery').toggle();
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/arow2oxa/2/)

It is necessary to select only the element corresponding to each panel.